# How to detect device and render appropriate image variation in Magnolia 5.7

Tags: magnolia

So far I successfully configure image variations in theme and render different variations of one image in ftl template

```
[#assign myAsset = damfn.getAsset("jcr","/futuristic_city_1.jpg")!]
[#if myAsset??]
    <img src="${myAsset.link}"/>
    [#assign myThumbnail = damfn.getRendition(myAsset, "240x180")!]
    [#if myThumbnail??]
        <img src="${myThumbnail.getLink()}"/>
    [/#if]
[/#if]
```

- I would use `Device Detection module` to detect incoming requests but can't find any guide or sample code on how to use it in FTL template to pick proper image variation.
- 2nd question is what should I use if the content is rendered with ReactJs components (their content loaded with JSON data retrieved from JCR)

Answer (score 0):

There is a community module to do that. It has a filter and attempts to detect the device upon request. For more information: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Device+Detection+module

Comment: I've mentioned that I'm aware of "Device Detection module" but can't find an example. Especially phrase "The channel is mapped to a variation. The variation consists of templates and a theme that optimizes the content for displaying on the device."  leaves me only question "How?"

Comment: @AlexeiP I'll delete my answer, I don't know the answer to your questions either :(

Answer (score 0):

the best and most modern way would be to define several image variants and define a set of responsive images.

the new html standards includes the attribute "srcset" for the img-tag:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

in a responsive website the best fitting image will be loaded by the browser